# Avoid Pop-up blocker when redirecting to a page in a new tab

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webforms

So, I have an a application that needs a report to be exported in PDF. And on button click the generated pdf should open in a new tab for the user to view the contents before downloading.

My problem is opening the page in a new tab gets a pop-up blocker warning, I already tried the following:

```
string url = "/Page2.aspx?id="+id+;

Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('"+url+"','_newtab')");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

.......

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"OpenWindow","window.open('"+url+"','_newtab');",true);
```

...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "NewTab", "window.open('" +url+ "');", true);
```

and still no progress. The redirecting should be done in the server side since I've got to get some data and passed it together with the link.

Comment: Will you try to use `<a href="some url" target="_newtab">content of the anchor</a>`

Comment: @Alex I need to do the redirecting in c# so I can't use the anchor tag solution.

Comment: May you try? `<a href="/Page2.aspx?id=123" target="_newtab">something</a>`, this will request the page2 from server in new tab, and also your c# code will run.  But this may not work if you need to do something with JavaScript before redirecting.

Comment: @Alex `_newtab` is not even a valid `target` attribute value. It's called `_blank`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a browser will block a popup unless the popup is initiated by the user.

If a window opens directly as a result of an onclick it will generally open okay. If the button click indirectly opens the window, it is more likely to be blocked. So your injecting a script tag etc. is likely to be blocked as a webpage being spammy (no-one wants unsolicited popups to appear when they browse).

Putting the window.open directly into the onclick event is the most likely solution to work.

Ultimately however you cannot control the behaviour of the browser though so it may not be possible to do what you want.

Changing the button into a styled hyperlink would work (with a target of _blank or similar). It is not possible to tell a browser to open in a new tab vs a new window.

Comment: So you're saying that what I want to achieve is impossible?